# Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, spring, saaj

I am trying to upgrade my project to java 15. While trying to launch the server I'm getting error during bean creation.

util-context.xml:

```xml
<beans:bean id="dummyAdaptor" class="org.dummy.adaptor.DummyAdaptor"></beans:bean>
<beans:bean id = "soapRequestProcessorWithAction" class="org.dummy.adaptor.request.processor.SOAPRequestProcessorWithAction" />
<beans:bean id="soapWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
   <beans:property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
   <beans:property name="unmarshaller" ref="unmarshaller" />
</beans:bean>
```

DummyAdaptor.java:

```
private SOAPRequestProcessorWithAction<CTRMProcessRequest, CTRMProcessResponse> soapRequestProcessorWithAction;
```

SOAPRequestProcessorWithAction.java:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("soapWebServiceTemplate")
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;
```

errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dummyAdaptor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'soapRequestProcessorWithAction'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'soapRequestProcessorWithAction': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webServiceTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapWebServiceTemplate' defined in class path resource [util-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'soapRequestProcessorWithAction': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'webServiceTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapWebServiceTemplate' defined in class path resource [util-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'soapWebServiceTemplate' defined in class path resource [util-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
        ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1310)
        ... 84 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:188)
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategies(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:134)
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:219)
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.getDefaultStrategy(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:203)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.initMessageFactory(WebServiceTemplate.java:353)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.initDefaultStrategies(WebServiceTemplate.java:342)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.<init>(WebServiceTemplate.java:130)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212)
        ... 86 more
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create SAAJ MessageFactory: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found; nested exception is javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:165)
        at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.instantiateBean(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:185)
        ... 98 more
**Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found**
        at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:112)
        at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:150)
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.afterPropertiesSet(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:143)
        ... 99 more
```

As per the solutions I found online i added below mentioned dependecy.

`compile group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version: '2.0.0'`

However in the `saaj-impl.jar` the `SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.class` in present at location `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl` instead of `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably you resolved the problem by now, but for future reference:

- `com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl` is the name of the `SAAJMetaFactory` distributed in JREs up to Java SE 8. It is the default factory used whenever no implementation of `javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory` is found on the classpath. In my opinion this is a bug: an external `jakarta.xml.soap-api` jar, shouldn't fall back to an internal JRE implementation of the API, but throw an exception stating that no implementation was found.
- you added `saaj-impl-2.0.0` to the classpath. However this is part of the new Jakarta EE 9 standard and uses `jakarta` instead of `javax` as prefix (i.e. it contains an implementation of `jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory`). Switch to version 1.5.2 and everything should work.

Comment: adding

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
      <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

solved it for me. I didn't need the System.setProperty commands other's suggested.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was not using the new Jakarta EE standard.  I set these two properties:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl");
System.setProperty("javax.xml.soap.MetaFactory","com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl");
```

Reason for both is that my local maven build + tomcat warned on MetaFactory to use SAAJMetaFactory instead but the server I deployed to only seems to use MetaFactory so I set both.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time struggling with this issue as well, and in my case I had to set the system property in my code:

```
System.setProperty("jakarta.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory", "com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl");
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the version 3.0.0 of `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl` at first and faced the same problem.

For me the issue was fixed when I switched the version to 1.4.0 -->

`implementation("com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:1.4.0")`